# Changing binding information leads to generic error in VisualStudio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I have an `ASP.NET` Website that works fine locally. As read in other posts I changed the binding information in order to make it available on my LAN - to easily access it from another machine during debugging.

I did the following:

1. ran VisualStudio 2015 as Administrator
2. edited `applicationhost.config` and changed the bindings information to: `*:52003:*`
3. added a firewall rule to accept incoming connection of port 52003

Now when I launch the Website within VisualStudio it refuses to start with this generic error:

> The operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the path specified.

Then it changes itself the `applicationhost.config` adding another Website with the default binding information (*:52003:localhost)

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to sync the changes with your project file,

https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b#.cjkfciley